# Collision occurs while storing and retrieving values from nsuserdefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have got two files namely `APIRequest.m` and `LoginController.m`.

APIRequest.m file has got a method receiveLoginData that contains the following code. status code will be received from server. If the credentials are all correct, the statuscode will be 1 else 0.  Im saving it to NSUserDefaults as follows.

**First block code:**

```
    - (void)receivedLoginData:(NSData *)data
{
    //NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // NSLog(@"%@",newStr);
    NSError *localError = nil;
    self.parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localError];
    NSString* loginResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSData *jsonData = [loginResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    NSString *statusCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonDic[@"status"]];

    self.statusCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonDic[@"status"]];
//     NSLog(@"Setting is %@", self.statusCode);
//     NSLog(@"%@",loginResponse );
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [prefs setObject:statusCode forKey:@"statusCode"];
    [prefs synchronize];

}
```

LoginController has got the following code. Over here im trying to retrieve the statuscode from NSUserDefaults by invoking `[self.request loginValidation];`

```
if (([self.request.usernameText isEqualToString:@""] && [self.request.passwordText isEqualToString:@""]) || ([self.request.usernameText isEqualToString:self.usernameTextField.text] && [self.request.passwordText isEqualToString:@""]) || ([self.request.usernameText isEqualToString:@""] && [self.request.passwordText isEqualToString:self.passwordTextField.text]))

        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Username or Password cant be left empty." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [self performSelector:@selector(select) withObject:self.request afterDelay:.1];
        } else{
            [self.request loginValidation];
            NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString* strValue =    [defaults objectForKey:@"statusCode"];
            NSLog(@"code %@",strValue);

        }
```

first time when i run the app and provide correct login credentials, the status code being set at APIRequest.m file is 1 so when its getting retrieved, the value is still 1.

second time i tried giving wrong login credentials and hence the status code set at APIRequest.m file is 0 but when its getting retrieved , the value is still 1. How can i solve this collision?

Comment: Don't use NSUserDefaults for communication within your app. Rather, invoke methods on the other class or use NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: can you please provide some code with reference to my code?

Comment: Not really as I am not entirely sure what is happening from the code you have shown,  i suspect that `loginValidation` completes asynchronously, so you need the completion block to post a notification or perhaps you can supply a completion block to the `loginValidation` method.

Comment: how can i replace nouserdefaults in my code with nsnotificationcenter?

Comment: Where is the first block of code used in relation to the second?

Comment: i have posted the first block code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the main problem, `[self.request loginValidation];` would call the code in a background thread, and wait until a response comes, and the bottom lines would get executed, without waiting for the login validation to actually finish.

A better way to do it would be call the function to check for login after you receive the data-->

```
self.statusCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonDic[@"status"]];
//     NSLog(@"Setting is %@", self.statusCode);
//     NSLog(@"%@",loginResponse );
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setObject:statusCode forKey:@"statusCode"];
[prefs synchronize];
[self confirmValidation];


-(void) confirmValidation
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* strValue =    [defaults objectForKey:@"statusCode"];
    NSLog(@"code %@",strValue);

}
```

Now, if they are not in the same class or cannot directly communicate, use Notification Center.

Its pretty simple, in the controller you are calling             `[self.request loginValidation];`, in the viewDidLoad or somewhere add a observer -->

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didSuccessfullyLogin:)
                                             name:@"didSuccessfullyLogin"
                                           object:nil];
```

And a function -->

```
- (void) didSuccessfullyLogin:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* strValue =    [defaults objectForKey:@"statusCode"];
    NSLog(@"code %@",strValue);
}
```

And finally,

```
self.statusCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonDic[@"status"]];
//     NSLog(@"Setting is %@", self.statusCode);
//     NSLog(@"%@",loginResponse );
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setObject:statusCode forKey:@"statusCode"];
[prefs synchronize];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"didSuccessfullyLogin"
 object:self];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to access it later?

Comment: Its there is defaults, you can always access that. Notification ensured you do not access it before its saved.

Comment: could not access it.

Comment: NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* strValue =    [defaults objectForKey:@"statusCode"];
    NSLog(@"code %@",strValue); --> This didn't work? Where are  you accessing it from? And what are you getting?

Comment: Both the methods work. Notification Center is very powerful for internal communication, do explore it! Happy to help!